# Unable to convert ssh key to base-64 string in Azure devops release classic UI pipeline

Tags: security, azure-devops

I have got a secure file with ssh key and uploaded this under Secure files in Azure Devops.

I have used Download secure file task within Azure DevOps **classic** **UI** release pipeline. I have got output variable as keys.secureFilePath

[image]

I want to convert the ssh key to Base-64 string using Powershell. I have used the code below for this.

```
Write-Host "Contents of cert.secureFilePath variable:"
Write-Host "$(cert.secureFilePath)"`
$filePath = $(cert.secureFilePath)

$encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String(
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(
   (Get-Content -Path $filePath -Raw -Encoding UTF8)
  )
)
```

It has the displayed the path fine D:\a_temp\cert.pem

But gives this error Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

I don't understand why it says path is null when it displayed the path fine, and also there is key in the file.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue. The reason is that the value of `securefilename.secureFilePath` can't be passed to other variable. If you print the value of `filePath`, you can see it's wrong. To fix this, use `cert.secureFilePath` directly in the scripts instead of using `filePath`.

For example,

```
Write-Host "The path of the secure file" $(securefilename.secureFilePath)
[convert]::ToBase64String((Get-Content -path $(securefilename.secureFilePath) -Encoding byte))
```

Comment: Thanks @Ziyang Liu-MSFT, it worked like a charm thank you so much.
Can I pass this encoded value in the override parameters directly?